# Hexadecimal value to ASCII

Tags: c++, hex, ascii

I have a question ASCII table.

If I have the following string :

```
string a = "\x25\x12";
```

How can I extract \x25 and \x12 separately so i can print their decimal corresponding ASCII values in C++?

Comment: `std::cout << static_cast<int>(a[0]) << " " << static_cast<int>(a[1]) << std::endl`

Comment: `cout << +a[0] << " " << +a[1] << "\n";`

Answer (score 2):

If this string is initialized like you presented (i.e. with literal in code), then it's already parsed by the compiler into two characters. You can simply iterate over it (or extract values with `[]` operator).

```
std::string a = "\x25\x12";
std::cout << a.length() << '\n'; //2
for(char c: a) 
{
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n'
          << static_cast<int>(a[0]) << ' '
          << static_cast<int>(a[1]) << ' '
```

If you read that string from any input (e.g. standard input or a file), you will have to *parse it* first.

---

As a side note, C++ implementations are free to choose any encoding, not necessarily ASCII compatible (although I don't know any compiler which doesn't use ASCII based encoding)